# Installing NetInfo on Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04, i can't find any tips how to install NetInfo module to work with network, I think it might be possible to do it in terminal, but i'm confused. I've tried to install  .exe file for windows of netInfo, Ubuntu has downloaded some additional files for opening windows related files , but still no result. Probably i need to try to open file for Mac OS ? Any ideas ?

Comment: `dnetinfo` is within the package [`dnet-progs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=netinfo&searchon=contents).

Answer (score 0):

netinfo seems to be in the package [openafs-client](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/openafs-client). You should be able to install it from the  Software Center.